# send the HTTP request python

Tags: python, http

When I send the HTTP request and the server response , I recieve some error like this

> "Received b'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: ...."

In addition, when it receives successful, how can we split the response two parts:

```
>The part before the \r\n\r\n sequence - the HEADER
>The part after the \r\n\r\n sequence - the DATA. 
>And Save the DATA to disk as a binary file
```

```
# Split URL into "host", "path", and "filename" variables.
# http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
#  * host=www.google.com
#  * path=/images/srpr
#  * file=logo3w.png

request = "GET "+path+filename +"/ HTTP/1.1" + "\nHost: " + host +"\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))

bytes_sent = s.send(send_request)

data = s.recv(64*1024)

print('Received', repr(data))

s.close()
```

Comment: if the questions is: how do I split data on a string, do `data.split("\r\n")` but unless you're trying to learn about http, just use `requests` library or some other higher level abstraction that handles this for you

Comment: For my current assignment, I have to do in this way

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be rougue `/` in your code.

```
request = "GET "+path+filename +"**/** HTTP/1.1" + "\nHost: " + host +"\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

The following works for me to fetch the image.

```
import socket

filename='logo3w.png'
host='www.google.com'
path='/images/srpr/'
request = "GET "+ path + filename +" HTTP/1.1" + "\nHost: " + host +"\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
print (request)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, 80))

bytes_sent = s.send(request.encode())

data = s.recv(64*1024)

print('Received', repr(data))

s.close()
```

Regarding your question as to how to split the data further, data.split mentioned by @Macattack in comments should work for you.